# Stream ajax/xhr content into page while loading

Tags: java, rest, dojo, xmlhttprequest

Is there a way to "stream" content into a page while the XHR/AJAX call is loading? I have setup a REST based Java servlet (Restlet), using JSP for templating, and am using JavaScript to generate all the content via Dojo XHR calls to the RESTlet. The downside to this is while I'm waiting for page elements to finish loading asynchronously, they do not display. Not a problem locally, but when SSH'd in even 60 KB can take a bit of time to dynamically load if I'm in a bad 3G area, less some JSON fetches are 1-6 MB in size.

And yes I realize JSON has no order guarantee.

I would like to render the content as it's downloaded, instead of waiting for the content to complete the asynchronous fetch and then call function to render it after the xhr request "on load".

Example:

```
function getFinanceData() {
    aniPreload("on");
    var thePostData = "doWhat=getFinanceData";
    var xhArgs = {
        preventCache: true,
        url: getResource("Finance"),
        postData: thePostData,
        handleAs: "json",
        timeout: timeOutMilli,
        load: function (data) {
            putAssets(
                    data.qMerged[0],
                    data.bGames,
                    data.books,
                    data.dTools,
                    data.licenses,
                    data.assets
                    );
            naviButtonListener();
            aniPreload("off");
        },
        error: function (data, iostatus) {
            aniPreload("off");
            window.alert("xhrGet for FinanceData FAIL!, STATUS: " + iostatus.xhr.status + " (" + data + ")");
        }
    };
    dojo.xhrPost(xhArgs);
}
```

Instead of load: function(data) { } I would like something like while loading function stream.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit jumbled, but... If 60K is taking a noticeable amount of time, you will have to live with that. For big transfers, where you want to see the beginning of the transfer while the rest completes, break the big request into smaller ones.

Update: I didn't mention this before, because would involve a lot of refactoring. But, I believe you could use WebSocket to achieve the streaming aspect. I didn't mention it before, however, because I'm not sure how streaming a long JSON is going to really help...

Comment: Right - but I'm wanting to stream it - read the data as it comes in - instead of wait for the AJAX / XHR request to complete then act on it.